# Get all entries for a BY variable

Tags: sas

I have an example data set

```
data test;
input ID 1-4
var1 $ 5-13
;
datalines;
1   Apples
2   Chocolate
3   Milk
3   Cocoa
3   Cake
3   Sugar
4   Marmelade
5   Banana
6   Rice
6   Beef
;
run;
```

I want to create a third variable all_names where I group all entries for var1 given that the ID appears multiple times. So for ID = 3, all_names should read "milk, cocoa, cake, sugar" and for ID = 6 it sould say "Rice, Beef".

I have some code that works but only in cases where ID appears twice:

```
 data step1;

  set test;

  by ID;


  prevID=lag(ID);
  prevVar1=lag(var1);

  if first.ID then prevID = . ;

  if ID eq prevID then all_names = cat(var1, ", ", prevVar1);

  else all_names = var1;
  
  drop prevID prevVar1;
  run;
```

How can I make my code work for cases where ID appears several times? I tried playing around with first.ID and last.ID but haven't figured it out yet. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want 10 obs in the resulting data or 1 obs for each unique ID?

Comment: 1 obs for each unique ID. I didn't want to make it to complicated so I didn't add that, figuring that I could delete the remaining lines later.

Comment: See the first approach below then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are solutions for if you want 10 obs in the resulting data (like in the input data) and one obs for each unique ID.

```
data test;
input ID 1-4
var1 $ 5-13
;
datalines;
1   Apples
2   Chocolate
3   Milk
3   Cocoa
3   Cake
3   Sugar
4   Marmelade
5   Banana
6   Rice
6   Beef
;
run; 

data want(drop = var1);

   do until (last.ID);
      set test;
      by ID;
      length all_names $200;
      all_names = catx(', ', all_names, var1);
   end;

run;

data want2;

   do until (last.ID);
      set test;
      by ID;
      length all_names $200;
      all_names = catx(', ', all_names, var1);
   end;

   do until (last.ID);
      set test;
      by ID;
      output;
   end;

run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way without a loop (and without lag function, which is a bit unintuitive to use when using by statement):

```
data have;
input ID 1-4
var1 $ 5-13
;
datalines;
1   Apples
2   Chocolate
3   Milk
3   Cocoa
3   Cake
3   Sugar
4   Marmelade
5   Banana
6   Rice
6   Beef
;
run;
```

If you want 10 obs:

```
data step1;
    set have;
    by ID;
    length all_names $200;
    retain all_names;
    if first.ID then all_names = var1;
    else all_names = cats(all_names,', ',var1);
run;
```

If you want only one obs for each unique ID just add this:

```
data step2;
    set step1 (drop=var1);
    by ID;
    if last.ID then output;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is so overcomplicated. I will just leave this simpler solution here.

```
/* If needed just to make sure it's sorted by ID for datastep group by processing */
proc sort data=test;
   by ID;
run;

data temp;
   set test;
   by ID;

   length all_names $200;
   retain all_names;
   
   all_names = catx(', ', all_names, var1);
   
   if last.ID then output;
   
   drop var1;
run;

proc sql;
   create table results as
      select t1.*, t2.all_names
      from test as t1, temp as t2
      where t1.ID = t2.ID
   ;
quit;
```

Comment: Can you point out the overcomplicated part of the accepted answer?

Comment: 1. Using set inside a loop when datastep itself is a loop
2. Joining two tables with presented way is most unreadable way of join implementation I've seen so far. Also without any additional benefits

Comment: 1. The Set statement inside a Do Loop is called a DoW Loop and is widely accepted among SAS programmers. 2. There are 0 joins occuring in the code. The want2 dataset (as described above the code) is probably the most efficient way to get the result if the OP wanted the original number of obs.

Comment: @PeterClemmensen Is want2 dataset more efficient way than mine loopless solution?

Comment: Yes. Given that the OP wanted 10 obs in the resulting data (not the case), the double DoW approach is more efficient. Is has 2 passes through the data. The approach above (results data set) has at least 2 passes through the original data (test) and at least 1 through the temp data. Also, it does not create the correct result.

Comment: @PeterClemmensen I meant compared to mine (3rd posted) solution, not fl0r3k's. It should have one pass through the data for 10 obs, and 2 for disctinct IDs. This one above (results) is obviously worse than DoW aproach as it has a needless join and on top of that doesn't produce a valid result.

Comment: With the DO UTIL around the SET statement you do not need to RETAIN the target variable  You also do not need to test for the start of a new by group so that the retained value can be cleared.  The value will be cleared by the starting of a new iteration.  The double loop adds more complexity, but with the benefit of the enhanced speed achieved by making both passes through a by group at once, which will allow the operating systems to cache the observations.